# How to match node name and execute things in Chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Attempting to match the node name to the string "mysql" and then do things in a recipe, but I'm not able to figure out the correct ruby+chef syntax.

Here's what I've got:

```
    if mysql.any? { |node| node.name.split('.')[0].include? node } do
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
```

Comment: You're testing that `node.name` includes...`node`? Do you mean `...[0] == 'mysql'`?

Comment: I'm assuming the .include does the same thing. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer finally.

```
if node['hostname'].include?  "mysql"
```

I'll be sure to use the attributes from now on. Hope it helps someone else who gets stuck.

Comment: `include?` tests that the string *includes* the text, not is equal to. If you mean to check `mysql2` or `main-mysql` as well, this will work.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to match anything that includes that string.